# How to display data labels vertical?

Tags: javascript, highcharts

Is it possible to make some of the data labels in this chart demo vertical? 
I saw that for all labels this can be achieved by adding a rotation property

```
plotOptions: {
 series: {
   dataLabels: {
     rotation: 90
   }
 }
}
```

but i would like to show those labels as vertical that are < 5% (Edge & Opera)

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/column-drilldown/)

Answer (score 0):

Remember that almost all `plotOptions` parameters can be set to individual series

```
            {
                "name": "Edge",
                "y": 4.02,
                "drilldown": "Edge",
                dataLabels:{
                        rotation:90,
                    y:-20
                }
            },
            {
                "name": "Opera",
                "y": 1.92,
                "drilldown": "Opera",
                dataLabels:{
                        rotation:90,
                    y:-20
                }
            },
```

[Doc](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.column.dataLabels) - [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/L457r4y1/)

Comment: I need a more dynamic approach here something like a callback function that would check the data label value and if is < 5% then display vertical... the demo fiddle is just an example for what i'm trying to do for my project, i don't want  to set things static myself

Comment: Its possible but you have to do it when you parse your data

Comment: How can i do that?

Comment: Look this [article](https://www.highcharts.com/docs/working-with-data/data-intro)

Comment: You check it before you create a chart - https://jsfiddle.net/gc5eueye/, or use point.update() after a chart is created https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Point#update